# Tmux within iTerm2: Unable to bind some keyboard combinations

Tags: iterm

I have the following bind-key definitions in my `.tmux.conf` file:

```
bind-key -n M-I select-pane -U
bind-key -n M-K select-pane -D
bind-key -n M-J select-pane -L
bind-key -n M-L select-pane -R
```

However, they don't work when I open a tmux session inside of ITerm2. It looks like the OS captures those shortcuts and doesn't let tmux act on them.

I have a similar problem when I press  <kbd>⌘-d</kbd> within ITerm (no Tmux here) in that it triggers Mac OS X to close my terminal, even though what I want it is to delete a word in the shell (I have `bindkey -e` in `.zshrc` which should take care of that)

Below are my settings in iTerm2:
  [image]